# Writing beautiful JSON using multiple line strings?

Tags: javascript, json

**Context**

For personal use, im creating a small project that documents my learning about data structures. I want to dynamically pull strings from a JSON file into a custom Vue component that displays code that can be run and edited in the browser by the user.

**The Probem**

[image: json image]

I find the above image far easier to, not only type, but also to read, than something like this (including variations including escape strings on a single line):

```js
   "BasicArithmic" : "var a = 1;var b = 2;var c = a + 5*b;return c;"
```

Ultimately i just want to be able to type the string out as multiple lines inside the code so that i'm not wasting my time trying to work out what code is supposed to do.

**Clarification**

Im passing in code as a string to an eval(), since i couldn't work out how to pass code between components and THEN convert the code to a string.

Comment: an array of strings maybe?

Answer (score -1):

Use ` instead of "

```js
console.log(`
a = 1;
b = 2;
`
)
```

Or you could add `\` to the end of each line:

```js
  x = { "BasicArithmic" : "\
  var a = 1;\
  var b = 2;\
  var c = a + 5*b;\
  return c;\
  "}
  console.log(x.BasicArithmic);
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support JavaScript template strings.

Comment: ...they already said they are using `eval`, so that doesn't really matter

Comment: I think they meant they were parsing the JSON normally and then parsing JS code embedded in strings in that JSON.

Comment: maybe, but if you're going to use eval, might as well just eval the whole thing if it gets you what you want